# My app does not appear in searches on the marketplace

Tags: firefox-os, marketplace

My app is available on the firefox marketplace at https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/shopping-list/

However if I search for "shopping" or "shopping list" in the marketplace app or on https://marketplace.firefox.com it does not appear anywhere.

What is going on ?

Comment: When did you publish it? What device does it not show up in the search results from?

Comment: The first version was published on december 13th, 2013 current version was uploaded on the 28th of april 2014. It does not show up on any device

Comment: Does it show "This app is unavailable for your platform." when browsing tot he app's page on your devices?

Comment: It does on the desktop but it doesn't when I open it with my phone in the web browser. I can't open it in the marketplace app on the phone though

Comment: BTW I managed to install the app by manually entering the url on my phone's browser

Comment: I just checked this on my phone and it shows up as the first entry when entering shopping list.

Comment: When I search for "Shopping List", your app is the first that appears.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how Firefox marketplace works, and should be addressed to their support staff

Answer (score 1):

Your app does not appear when searching the Firefox Marketplace from Desktop or Android because we filter search results to show only apps that will work on the device you are searching from, and you did not check the boxes to say that it is available on desktop or android. Like Jason, I easily found your app when searching from my Firefox OS phone.

Comment: Not for me. I just installed 2.0 on my phone though could that be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Gi,

Marketplace reviewer here. Your app is public and has the following requirements:
IndexedDB, Smartphone-Sized Displays (qHD), Vibration.

You should be able to find it, no matter what version you are using.

My guess is that your are using any hyphen to look for it. If you try using "shopping", it will be in the third place:

[image: This is what I find using a Flame 2.1]

Comment: Thanks for dropping by, but it definitely does not appear. I'm using Firefox OS 2.0 I compiled myself on a Flame device.
Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/hcfpBaJ.png

Comment: It seems that it's a bug. He have filled a report to fix it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1055513